# Morse Translator in Python

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, morse-code

I am a beginner in Python, and I made a Morse translator that converts letters to Morse, and Morse to letters (where a decimal point is 'dot' and underscore is 'dash'). Is there any way I could make my code shorter and more efficient? For reference, [here's the translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code) of Morse to letter characters.

```
dot = '.'
dash = '_'
letter_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S',
               'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
morse_list = [dot + dash, dash + dot * 3, dash + dot + dash + dot, dash + dot * 2, dot, dot * 2 + dash + dot,
              dash * 2 + dot, dot * 4, dot * 2, dot + dash * 3, dash + dot + dash, dot + dash + dot * 2,
              dash * 2, dash + dot, dash * 3, dot + dash * 2 + dot, dash * 2 + dot + dash, dot + dash + dot,
              dot * 3, dash, dot * 2 + dash, dash * 3 + dot, dot + dash * 2, dash + dot * 2 + dash,
              dash + dot + dash * 2, dash * 2 + dot * 2]
# The for loop below prints the entire translation (Eg. 'A: ._ B: _...') so the user could reference it
for n in range(len(letter_list)):
    print(letter_list[n] + ': ' + morse_list[n], sep=' ', end=' ', flush=True)
while True:
    print("\nTYPE 'EXIT' if you want to EXIT.")
    user_input = input("INPUT LETTERS OR MORSE CHARACTERS (DECIMAL AND UNDERSCORE) TO CONVERT."
                       "\nSEPERATE LETTERS WITH SPACES: ")
    # Converts user input into an iterable list
    user_list = user_input.split()
    if user_input == 'EXIT':
        print("THANK YOU FOR USING THE MORSE TRANSLATOR")
        break
    for i in range(len(user_list)):
        if user_list[i] in letter_list:
            for n in range(len(morse_list)):
                if user_list[i] == letter_list[n]:
                    print(morse_list[n], sep=' ', end='  ', flush=True)
        elif user_list[i] in morse_list:
            for n in range(len(letter_list)):
                if user_list[i] == morse_list[n]:
                    print(letter_list[n], sep=' ', end='  ', flush=True)
```

Comment: Yes. Mixed translations are allowed. So if the user inputs 'A ._' it will output, '._ A'

Comment: I would suggest a `dictionary`

Comment: Since the morse code are known at compile time, why calculate them? You should simply map `A:  '.-'` instead, this saves the multiplication and addition cost

Comment: @theProgrammer Thank you for the tips. The reason I did not map it was because I might want to change the value of dot and dash. So dot could be either ```• and —``` rather than ```. and _```. If it's in a variable, i would only have to change 2 lines, rather than an entire dictionary.

Comment: `Concatenation` of strings are relatively expensive but its okay for this scenario, but do keep that in mind.

Answer (score 11):

1. Since it is really difficult to tell what letter maps to what, it will be much easier to validate your code (for yourself & future maintainers) if you write out the dictionary directly:

```py
CHAR_TO_MORSE = {
    'A': '._',
    'B': '_...',
    'C': '_._.',
    'D': '_..',
    'E': '.',
    'F': '.._.',
    'G': '__.',
    'H': '....',
    'I': '..',
    'J': '.___',
    'K': '_._',
    'L': '._..',
    'M': '__',
    'N': '_.',
    'O': '___',
    'P': '.__.',
    'Q': '__._',
    'R': '._.',
    'S': '...',
    'T': '_',
    'U': '.._',
    'V': '___.',
    'W': '.__',
    'X': '_.._',
    'Y': '_.__',
    'Z': '__..',
}
MORSE_TO_CHAR = {v: k for k, v in CHAR_TO_MORSE.items()}
CHAR_OR_MORSE_TO_INVERSE = {**CHAR_TO_MORSE, **MORSE_TO_CHAR}
```

2. Avoid string concatenation (`+`) when possible (mostly for performance):

```py
print(' '.join("{}: {}".format(k, v) for k, v in CHAR_TO_MORSE.items()))
```

3. Very minor but check exit condition before parsing:

```py
if user_input == 'EXIT':
    break
user_list = user_input.split()
```

4. What happens if the input contains neither a single char nor valid morse? Your program will eat it, potentially at the confusion of the user. Maybe you can default to printing a question mark; something like:

```py
print(' '.join(CHAR_OR_MORSE_TO_INVERSE.get(c, '?') for c in user_list))
```

Note that this uses a single dictionary lookup per item `user_list`, which is about as efficient as you could ask for.

Comment: +1 for the nice review. There is an extra `{` after `CHAR_TO_MORSE` and a missing `)` in the first print. The first print can also be shorten using f-strings: `print(' '.join(f'{k}: {v}' for k, v in CHAR_TO_MORSE.items()))`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to store characters in a list when you can do it in a string.

Instead of the confusion index checks all over your code, use can usea 2 python `dict`:

```
dot = '.'
dash = '_'
letter_list = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
morse_list = [dot + dash,
              dash + dot * 3,
              dash + dot + dash + dot,
              dash + dot * 2, dot,
              dot * 2 + dash + dot,
              dash * 2 + dot,
              dot * 4, dot * 2,
              dot + dash * 3,
              dash + dot + dash,
              dot + dash + dot * 2,
              dash * 2,
              dash + dot, dash * 3,
              dot + dash * 2 + dot,
              dash * 2 + dot + dash,
              dot + dash + dot,
              dot * 3, dash,
              dot * 2 + dash,
              dash * 3 + dot,
              dot + dash * 2,
              dash + dot * 2 + dash,
              dash + dot + dash * 2,
              dash * 2 + dot * 2]

dct = dict(list(zip(letter_list, morse_list)) + list(zip(morse_list, letter_list)))

print(" ".join(f"{k}: {dct[k]}" for k in dct))

while True:
    print("\nTYPE 'EXIT' if you want to EXIT.")
    user_input = input("INPUT LETTERS OR MORSE CHARACTERS (DECIMAL AND UNDERSCORE) TO CONVERT."
                       "\nSEPERATE LETTERS WITH SPACES: ")
    if user_input == 'EXIT':
        print("THANK YOU FOR USING THE MORSE TRANSLATOR")
        break
    user_list = user_input.split()
    print(" ".join(dct.get(i) for i in user_list))
```

---

For more understanding of what `dict(list(zip(letter_list, morse_list)) + list(zip(morse_list, letter_list)))` does:

- `list(zip([1, 2, 3], "abc"))` would return `[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]`
- `list(zip("abc", [1, 2, 3]))` would return `[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]`
- `list(zip([1, 2, 3], "abc")) + list(zip("abc", [1, 2, 3]))` would return `[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), ('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]`
- `dict(list(zip([1, 2, 3], "abc")) + list(zip("abc", [1, 2, 3])))` would return `{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}`

---

UPDATE:

```
d = dict(zip(letter_list, morse_list))
d.update(zip(morse_list, letter_list))
```

is more efficient than

```
d = dict(list(zip(letter_list, morse_list)) + list(zip(morse_list, letter_list)))
```

Credits to GZ0 and superb rain in the comments.